# Ubuntu 20.04 DNS 100% Packet loss. Able to connect to LAN but not WAN

Tags: networking, internet, dns

First time asking a question on this forum.

So I was using a dell Inspiron 5547 with Ethernet. Recently I had to change my router’s location so I had to switch from Ethernet to 5ghz WiFi. Now I am unable to receive incoming pings.
I have made no modifications to any firewall or related settings on both the PC and router. The only change I made prior to this was trying out Adobe Acrobat Reader with wine. The PC was alright post uninstalling it too.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Results in x transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time x.

```
ping www.google.com
```

Results in same as above.

Pinging 192.168.1.1 which is my router gateway ip works fine.

Pinging anything else does not work.

Based on other forum posts I tried traceroute but I do not have net-tools installed and have no way of doing so AFAIK.

I tried to move the laptop and use Ethernet but the same problem occurs on Ethernet and USB Tethering as well.

Apt-get update and —-fix-missing also don’t work.

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are unable to ping, which is ICMP not DNS. It could be that your router is in "AP isolation" or "Client isolation" mode which prevents communication between clients on the network. Check your router for a setting named something like that and disable it.

What happens if you try `ping www.google.com` if it starts pinging an IP address, then you do not have a problem with DNS.

Comment: Results are similar to above. Also the router settings have not been changed, and the PC did work before.

Comment: Under SSID configuration, Isolation was set to disable.